# Windows Phone PhotoCamera orientation

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, silverlight-toolkit

I am writing an application using the microsoft FaceSDK for real time face tracking using the Front camera. I am using PhotoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY() to get the real time image and process it.

The problem is , I want my code to work in portrait mode. I can orient the camera image on screen by using appropriate transforms, but it seems, the PhotoCamera.GetPreviewBufferY() always gives me the image in the default landscape orientation. Is there anyway to change the photocamera live viewfinder orientation before processing it? 
OR
I could also manipulate the byte[] so as to change the orientation of image by 90 or 270 degree. But because this is a real time application, a fast method would be needed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post any code? Anyway this is a simple guide of microsoft: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)